# Tag synonym request: [pop-forgotten-sands] & [prince-of-persia-fs] (Prince of Persia: The Forgotten Sands)

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I requested this because of this question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107467/graphics-are-glitching-out, a question about [Prince of Persia: The Forgotten Sands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia:_The_Forgotten_Sands).

It was tagged [prince-of-persia-fs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia-fs), [at one point](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/107467/3), but was [then retagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/107467/4) to [pop-forgotten-sands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pop-forgotten-sands). It might be useful if one is a synonym of another, so that when a user types in 'prince...' or  'pop...' in the tags text box, they'll get a proper tag suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a thing that has happened.